# Understanding VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have some problems with Excel and I don't know VBA. Can someone please help me understand these lines?

```
 Range("B4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.Goto Reference:="Übersicht!R[8]C[11]"
    Sheets("Korrekturbuchung").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Übersicht").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: The Macro Recorder records each user action as it occurs.  The result is poor quality VBA.  For example, `Select` is not recommended because it a slow command and makes the VBA difficult to understand.  The Macro Recorder does not know your objective so this is the best it can do.

Comment: Trying to learn VBA with the Macro Recorder is a bad idea.  There are any number of free, online Excel VBA tutorials.  Try a few and then finish the one that is best for you.  I prefer books.  I went to a large library and looked at all the Excel VBA primers.  I borrowed the best two or three to try at home.  I bought the one that was best for me as a permanent reference.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at that, some of what you did didn't achieve anything (this is always the way when recording a macro rather than typing code, as it records things like scrolling)

Here's a few pointers, though. Each line is a different operation.

- `Range("B4").Select` - selects Cell B4
- `Selection.Copy` - the selected cell or range is copied. So these two rows could be shortened into `Range("B4").Copy`
- But then you have `Application.CutCopyMode = False` which turns off copying in Excel, so you lose whatever was on the clipboard.
- There are other lines there selecting sheets - fairly obvious which ones those are
- The first thing I would do with this would be, wherever one line finishes with `.select` and the next starts with `selection.`, delete both of those and join the two lines (see point 2)
- Another good way to learn what each line does is to hit F8 repeatedly while in the sub in the VBA editor (with the file visible in another monitor or something) and it will go through the sub line-by-line

Comment: I'd add that `Range("B4").Select` will select B4 on whichever sheet is active when the code runs - even if it's a different file.  `="Übersicht!R[8]C[11]"` will then look 8 rows down, 11 rows across from B4 or return an error if the active file doesn't have that sheet.  So it will be `M12` if `B4` is selected, but `L12` if `A4` is selected.  If you always want `M12` then `"R12C13"` (row 12, column 13) would be better.